# Segmentation fault in list of objects

Tags: c++, design-patterns, vector, segmentation-fault, copy-constructor

I didn't thought that this would be so hard, but I have the following program:
In a multithreaded environment (using the ACE-Framework and OpenMP) I use the Observer pattern.

In the init-routine of the Observer-controller-thread (ActiveObject) I create a vector of *ConcreteObservers* (for notifying them with their discrete job) like this:

```
mResynthesisVec.assign(cMaxEDTDetection, ConcreteResynthesis(pClientObj));
```

Until now I have used only standard POD-Types in the class, so the standard copy-constructor didn't make any problems.
But today I expanded the ConcreteObserver-class with a vector of the std::complex-type. I thought that the vector has already in-type copy-constructor capability, but all I get is a segmentation fault, right after creating the ConcreteObserver. So why doesn't that work?

**EDIT:**
The thread *Resynthesis* is an ACE::ActiveObject (Thread) and maintains the observers. This thread has a Subject *mEventMonitor* as a member variable, which controls all concrete-observers (*ConcreteResynthesis*), which are created and stored in a std::vector in the init-routine of *Resynthesis* (as shown above). As soon jobs to perform come from another program over TCP, *Resynthesis* registers the needed number of concrete-observers at the Subject and "notifies" respectively gives them their work to do.

```
typedef std::complex<float> TComplexType;
typedef std::vector<TComplexType> TFFTContainer;
typedef TFFTContainer::iterator TFFTContIter;
typedef std::vector<float> TWindowContainer;

class ConcreteResynthesis: public Subject::Observer {

public:
    ConcreteResynthesis();
    ConcreteResynthesis(TCPClient * client);
    virtual ~ConcreteResynthesis();
    virtual void Notify(TBinPos value, int workSignal, int shotCntr, int     shots);    /// Function called by observed Subject
... some methods
        private:
    TBinPos mPos;   ///< Last observed value
    TCPClient * pClientObj;
    TFFTContainer mFFTDataCont;    //makes the problem
    fftwf_plan mFFTWPlan;
    unsigned int mCurrentLength;
    unsigned int mSignalPos;
    TFFTContainer tFullSignal;   //makes the problem

        };
```

The constructor of *ConcreteResynthesis* looks like this

```
ConcreteResynthesis::ConcreteResynthesis(TCPClient *client) : ///<avaroa(0),
        pClientObj(client) {

    fftwf_init_threads();   ///< does only need to be called once, so do it here

}
```

And the virtual destructor is empty in *ConcreteResynthesis*

In *Resynthesis* after defining the working area, I notify the conrete-observers it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < iSignalCntr; ++i)
    mEventMonitor.ConcreteNotify(pClientObj->GetBinPositions(i), i, sBurstCounter, sBursts);
```

The thing is that the observers are created once in the init-routine of *Resynthesis* so till I get a job only the constructors of *ConcreteResynthesis* are called. But with the vector in the class I get the segmentation fault after the creation of the first concrete-observer

**EDIT2**
As suggested I implemented the copy constructor, destructor and assignment operator. But I still get the segmenattoin fault. In the destructor I set the pointers to zero because for the deletion is another thread responsible. Below you can see 'the rule of 3' implementation:

Assignment operator (almost the same for the copy constructor, but wothpout returning this-pointer and without the if-statement)

```
ConcreteResynthesis & ConcreteResynthesis::operator=(const ConcreteResynthesis & rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
        mRange = rhs.mRange;
        pClientObj = rhs.pClientObj;
        pDataPool = rhs.pDataPool;
        tFullSignal = rhs.tFullSignal;
        mPos = rhs.mPos;    ///< Last observed value
        mFFTDataCont = rhs.mFFTDataCont;
        mZeroBytes2Add = rhs.mZeroBytes2Add;
        mNextPowOf2 = rhs.mNextPowOf2;
        //mFile = rhs.mFile;
        mFFTWPlan = rhs.mFFTWPlan;
        mFFTW_WisdomString = 0;
        //mutable ACE_Thread_Mutex mMutex;  ///< A mutex to guard the value
        mCurrentLength = rhs.mCurrentLength;
        mSignalPos = rhs.mSignalPos;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Virtual destructor:

```
ConcreteResynthesis::~ConcreteResynthesis() {

    pClientObj = 0;
    pDataPool = 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning, changed it to c++

Comment: There you go - now you have syntax highlighting !

Comment: The default copy ctor should be able to copy a vector. You should try to build a MVCE.

Comment: if you mean MVC, then I must say I am using Linux, with a standard console project

Comment: @mbed_dev You've given us one line of code with variables we have no idea about.  How are we to help you to solve this problem with such little information?  The only thing we can tell you is that your program has a bug.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie added some piece of code. I hope it is helpful

Comment: @mbed_dev `TCPClient * pClientObj`  Your `ConcreteResynthesis` class contains this member, you are placing `ConreteResynthesis` in a vector, and vector will be making copies.  What does your `ConcreteResynthesis` destructor do?  In other words, your `ConcreteResynthesis` class may not be safely copyable and cannot be used in a vector safely (unless it has correct copy semantics, i.e. follows the rule of 3).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've now implemented 'the rule of 3' (code is above) and I still get the segmentation fault. pClientObj is created somewhere else (it's a thread and my thread manager class is responsible for it's destruction) so in the concrete-observer-objects I set the member-pointer to 0. What else could it be, or is my implementation above wrong?

Comment: You should make the pointer a `std::shared_ptr<TCPClient>` instead of a raw pointer.  This way, deletion occurs when the last instance that has a hold of the pointer gets deleted automatically.  Then you don't need a user-defined destructor, assignment operator, or copy constructor.  In any event, your assignment operator need not do all of that code.  All you need to do is to use the copy constructor and destructor to do a copy / swap.  No need to reimplement all of that logic.

Comment: Also this `mFFTW_WisdomString = 0;` in your assignment operator breaks the contract that the objects are copies.  It should be this: `mFFTW_WisdomString = rhs. mFFTW_WisdomString;`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie using the shared pointer helped. Thanks!

Comment: @mbed_dev Updated with an answer.  Upvote if it helps solve the issue you were having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not solve all of your issues, but one thing you should do is to have your `TCPClient` pointer as a `std::shared_ptr` instead of a raw pointer.

Given your description, you are indeed sharing the pointer between instances due to your usage of `std::vector<ConcreteResynthesis>`.  You also mentioned that you are manually deallocating the pointer in your thread manager after everything is done.  This seems to be a use case for `std::shared_ptr`.

Your `ConcreteResynthesis` class has the following members:

```
TBinPos mPos;   ///< Last observed value
TCPClient* pClientObj;
TFFTContainer mFFTDataCont;    //makes the problem
fftwf_plan mFFTWPlan;
unsigned int mCurrentLength;
unsigned int mSignalPos;
TFFTContainer tFullSignal;   //makes the problem
```

By changing to this:

```
#include <memory>
//...
TBinPos mPos;   ///< Last observed value
std::shared_ptr<TCPClient> pClientObj;
TFFTContainer mFFTDataCont;    //makes the problem
fftwf_plan mFFTWPlan;
unsigned int mCurrentLength;
unsigned int mSignalPos;
TFFTContainer tFullSignal;   //makes the problem
```

When copies of instances of `ConcreteResynthesis` objects are invoked, the shared pointer will bump up the reference count.  Each object in the vector will be using the same single pointer.  When the last entity that uses the shared pointer is destroyed (the destruction makes the reference count 0), then the pointer is finally deleted.

With all the copying and destruction going on internal to `std::vector`, the `std::shared_ptr` member takes care of all of the work, which your destructor (now no longer needed) was attempting to do in an inelegant way (setting the pointer to 0, in a sort of a "poor man's move constructor" type of fashion).

In addition to this, you do not need a user-defined copy constructor, assignment operator, or destructor, making the code much cleaner and less likely to have bugs.

Note that with all this, I am assuming that the base class `Subject::Observer` is also copyable with no issues.